# Unable to run Ruby gem in separate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, binaryfiles

Below is a gem I created simply for the purpose of opening a text/README.md file and pulling out the first and last line. The gem build properly, however if I attempt to run a separate file that calls the gem I've built I receive the following error message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nrodruck_test_gem-0.0.1/bin/test_gem:8:in 
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant TestGem::Myfile (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/test_gem:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/test_gem:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Below is the file I'm attempting to use to run my gem. This file takes a command line in put in which you specify the file you want my gem to read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'test_gem'

puts "test_gem script executing"
puts ARGV[0]

puts TestGem::MyFile.first( ARGV[0] )
```

Here is the gem:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../test_gem", __FILE__)

require 'version'
require 'hello'

module TestGem

  puts "module TestGem defined"

  class MyFile

    def self.first(filename)
        File.open(filename, "r") {|f| f.readline}
    end

    def self.last(filename)
        File.open(filename, "r")[-1]
    end 
  end   
end
```

EDIT

Typo fixed per the comment, still receiving the same error message.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nrodruck_test_gem-0.0.1/bin/test_gem:8:
in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant TestGem::Myfile (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/test_gem:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/test_gem:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typo. You typed it as `Myfile` when trying to call it, instead of `MyFile`, the name of the constant.

Comment: Fixed the typo and and receiving the exact same error.

Comment: @NealR: Exact same? Edit your question with the type fixed and the new  error.

Comment: @NealR: Are you sure that the error doesn't now say `uninitialized constant TestGem::MyFile`? (Capital F)?

Comment: Edited my post per your comments

Comment: I noticed that the typo is still there. Do I need to rebuild the gem?

Comment: @NealR: Then you arn't running the new code. if you fixed the typo, you never access a `TestGem::Myfile`.

Comment: @NealR: Try rebuilding.

Comment: @NealR: good! Glad it worked.